# Are simple main effects different from separate tests performed at each level?

Tags: hypothesis-testing, anova, interaction, interpretation

If there is a significant interaction in ANOVA, we do not interpret the main effects and instead calculate the simple main effects (difference between groups at each level of one of the categorical variables). I wanted to ask - How is this different from just performing the separate tests at each level? I know that the output is largely the same, but is there a difference in power, or some other statistical difference?

Comment: When you perform a collection of separate tests, take a closer look at the output.  Do they agree on their estimates of the residual mean squared error?

Answer (score 1):

Compare the outputs: when you do a bunch of separate tests, each test will use its own variance estimate. Each of this estimates will have lower degrees of freedom, so lower precision, than a common (pooled) estimate.

If an assumption of equal variances is (approximately) true, this will lose information, and yes, lose power. In some cases this power loss could be quite large.